# shifting decimal point using vim, shell or python

Tags: python, shell, vim

I have a .pl file that consists of an unstructured header and some specific X Y Z structure. The header has no "." in there. Below you can find a snippet of this file:

```
Header (in total 29 lines)
ILINE
VRTX 1 545057.78564453125 3800905.201171875 -15000 
VRTX 2 545184.49072265625 3800765.451171875 -15000 
VRTX 3 545310.91650390625 3800625.970703125 -15000 
SEG 1 2 
SEG 2 3 
ILINE
VRTX 136 551295.84606933594 3799015.443359375 -15000 
VRTX 137 551293.82849121094 3798841.880859375 -15000 
VRTX 138 551290.57849121094 3798661.892578125 -15000  
SEG 136 137 
SEG 137 138
```

What I like to achieve is to shift the decimal point of my X and Y values to the left like this:

```
VRTX 1 5450.5778564453125 38009.05201171875 -15000 
VRTX 2 5451.8449072265625 38007.65451171875 -15000 
VRTX 3 5453.1091650390625 38006.25970703125 -15000
```

I think that regular expressions could help but I have no experiences in that using Python nor Shell. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider alternatively reading in as numbers and multiplying by 100?

Comment: @Yunnosch divide by 100

Comment: @Yunnosch That removes precision.

Comment: Considering yes, but I am not sure how I can do it

Comment: This should work in vim, if all your lines look similar `:g /VRTX/ normal f.xhhi.<C-v><Esc>f.xhhi.`

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You might be right. However, moving the decimal point with a regex will end up loosing the same amount of precision, at least once the resulting number is evaluated. This is of course assuming that the values end up being evaluated in the same environment in which the moving/multiplying is done.

Comment: @Yunnosch And that's a moderate assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a vim tag on the question:

```
/\.
qaqqanx2hi!<esc>@aq
@a
:%s/!/./g
```

Assuming there is no `!` in the text, else you have to substitute it with a different character(s). Of course there are other solutions in vim, but that's the simplest which I can think of right now.

Breakdown:

```
 /\.                  " searches every `.` in the file 
                      " (and "marks" them as searchresults)

qaqqanx2hi!<esc>@aq   " Our macro we use:
qaq                   " records an empty macro into register a 
                      " (This ensures the register is empty)
   qa                 " This starts recording a macro into register a again
     nx2hi!<esc>      " `n` jumps to the next search result,  
                      " `2hxhi!<esc>` inserts a `!` 2 chars left of where
                      " the `.` has been, and exits insert mode
                @a    " calls the macro at register `a`, since we emptied it,
                      " nothing happens yet, but once we save this macro it will
                      " be in register `a`. So it will call itself until it 
                      " reaches an abort conditions (no more `.` found in the
                      " text, thats why we replace `.` with `!` here, else
                      " the macro would move the `.` over and over to the left
                  q   " Stops recording the macro and saves it (to register `a`)

@a                    " calls the macro in register `a`

:%s/!/./g             " This just replaces all `!` in the file with `.`
```

**Possible cleaner solution: Use nowrapscan** (thanks @Francesco)

```
/\.
:set nows
qaqqax3hpn@aq
@a
:set ws
```

Note: The Macro changes order a bit. We must first change the position of the `.` and then jump to the next search-occurence else we will miss the first occurence, since the search doesn't wrap arround eof anymore.

Note: It would be better to save the state of `ws` before and then restore it. But that would only matter in a generic version.

**Conclusion**

Complicated but flexible solution. If you don't need to be flexible, the other vim solutions here are easier (I will not judge other solutions)

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. Could you please add some explanation what it does.

Comment: sure thing, did a bit of explaining, just ask if you have some more questions

Comment: Why not just insert the directly `.` instead of putting in a `!` then doing a substitution at the end? `nx2hP` vs `nx2hi!`

Comment: @PeterRincker because the macro won't stop then. `n` will jump back to top (to the first `.`) and move the `.` further left again. But I may miss something, as always I am happy to get corrected/improved.

Comment: something that i was thinking to simplify the macro approach was to disable search wrap

Comment: of course, `nows`, i was pretty sure there was a paramter to turn it off, but just couldn't remember, thanks @Francesco

Answer (score 5):

A copy and paste friendly vim solution

```
:g/VRTX/normal f.xhhP;xhhP
```

explanation:

- **:g/{pattern}/command** - executes command on every line matching pattern. In this case every *VRTX* line
- **normal** - the commands we want to execute are normal mode commands
- **f.** - find the first dot in current line
- **xhhP** - cut such character, move left two times, paste
- **;** - find next occurrence
- **xhhP** - move dot again

Comment: That's also a good solution which I've had in mind, but it only works if there are never more then two numbers on the same line. After looking at it again, this most certainly is the case, which makes your answer better than mine for the given usecase!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` to do that, here's one-line command,

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(match($i,/[0-9][0-9]\./))$i=substr($i,0,RSTART-1)"."substr($i,RSTART,2)substr($i,RSTART+3)}1' input_file
```

Brief explanation,

1. Scan all fields in each record
2. `match($i,/[0-9][0-9]\./`: Check if any field is matched regex `[0-9][0-9]\.`
3. Since `awk` would record the the start point in `RSTART` for the matched case. We can use `substr` function and `RSTART` information to regenerate the filed to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Python. First, we define a function that moves the decimal around for us.

```
SEARCH = '.'
OFFSET = -2

def replacer(bits):
   if SEARCH in bits:
      loc = bits.index(SEARCH)+OFFSET
      return ''.join('{}.'.format(x) if k == loc-1 else x for k,x in enumerate(bits.replace('.','')))
   else:
      return bits
```

Next, apply it to the lines:

```
s = """Header (in total 29 lines)
ILINE
VRTX 1 545057.78564453125 3800905.201171875 -15000 
VRTX 2 545184.49072265625 3800765.451171875 -15000 
VRTX 3 545310.91650390625 3800625.970703125 -15000 
SEG 1 2 
SEG 2 3 
ILINE
VRTX 136 551295.84606933594 3799015.443359375 -15000 
VRTX 137 551293.82849121094 3798841.880859375 -15000 
VRTX 138 551290.57849121094 3798661.892578125 -15000  
SEG 136 137 
SEG 137 138"""

>>> for i in s.split('\n'): 
..   if i.startswith('VRTX'): 
..     print(' '.join(map(replacer, i.split(' '))))

VRTX 1 5450.5778564453125 38009.05201171875 -15000 
VRTX 2 5451.8449072265625 38007.65451171875 -15000 
VRTX 3 5453.1091650390625 38006.25970703125 -15000 
VRTX 136 5512.9584606933594 37990.15443359375 -15000 
VRTX 137 5512.9382849121094 37988.41880859375 -15000 
VRTX 138 5512.9057849121094 37986.61892578125 -15000
```

Answer (score 1):

My regex solution

```
:%s,\v(\d\d)\.,.\1,g

\v ...... very magic to avoid many backslashes
(\d\d) .. regex group one
\. ...... literal dot
\1 ...... reference to regex group one
```

Comment: This is in my opinion actually the best vim solution here. It is really really easy (Should have thougth of that). Has no constraint on the number of `.` as francesco's solution has. Should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
new_data = ''
for line in data.splitlines():
    if '.' in line:
        mod_line = ''
        for word in line.split():
            if '.' in word:
                try:
                    float(word)
                    word = re.sub(r'(\d\d)\.', r'.\1', word)
                except:
                    pass
            mod_line += word + ' '
        new_data += mod_line.rstrip() +'\n'
    else:
        new_data += line + '\n'

new_data = new_data.rstrip()
print (new_data)
```

**Output**

```
ILINE
VRTX 1 5450.5778564453125 38009.05201171875 -15000
VRTX 2 5451.8449072265625 38007.65451171875 -15000
VRTX 3 5453.1091650390625 38006.25970703125 -15000
SEG 1 2 
SEG 2 3 
ILINE
VRTX 136 5512.9584606933594 37990.15443359375 -15000
VRTX 137 5512.9382849121094 37988.41880859375 -15000
VRTX 138 5512.9057849121094 37986.61892578125 -15000
SEG 136 137 
SEG 137 138
```

Comment: This solution modifies the input, you are losing one digit of precision.

Comment: Should be fixed now